# jquery.ui won't load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am loading jquery and Jquery.ui. Jquery loads fine. Jquery.ui does not. Here are my statements:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

And here is where I test:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Checking if jQuery UI is loaded or not
if($.ui && $.ui.version){
    // jQuery UI is loaded

    alert("Loaded");
}else {
   alert("Not loaded");
}
});
</script>
```

That code returns 'Undefined'. I have tried variations of above code including testing for if (jQuery.ui), etc. Same results.

I have tried loading jquery.ui from local files as well as Google with same results. I need another set of eyes. JS debugger shows 200 for jquery.ui.

Comment: Copied that code over and ran it, alerts "Loaded" for me.

Comment: did you check your JS debug console to see if jquery really is being loaded? you're simply asssuming it is.

Comment: All of my jquery functions in the script do execute. My jquery.ui functions do not.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6w9d3pho/

Comment: Where are you seeing "Undefined"? The alert should either be "Loaded" or "Not loaded".

Comment: Yeah, sorry. one of the testing permutations was set to show defined or undefined. The one I posted shows 'Not Loaded'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bj2m7er8/ this fiddle shows a working jQuery UI dialog with the same versions of the libraries you're pulling in. If you're in an office environment, be sure a firewall isn't blocking the CDN verions, check your debug console. Might be an interesting test to load them locally instead of from CDN.

Comment: loaded them locally with the same result. Odd thing is, I have other scripts running on the same server that load it just fine.

Comment: Can you show one or two errors from the application code?

Comment: @mikehomme. jquery.ui dialog() returns: not a function

Comment: Ok, as expected if it's not loaded. When you go here jsfiddle.net/bj2m7er8 do you get "Loaded" or "Not Loaded"?

Comment: It displays loaded at jsfiddle.net/bj2m7er8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63614/discussion-between-mikehomme-and-len-d).

Answer (score -1):

to Checking if jQuery UI is loaded or not

```
if (jQuery.ui) {
  // UI loaded
}
```

OR

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
  // UI loaded
}
```

Try it

Comment: What is the difference between what you're doing here and what the OP did?